# awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last

Tags: awk

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html
based on section 1.1.2 1.1.2 Running awk Without Input Files
I can understand   `awk '{print $0}' marks.txt`
it's just like echo. it will return

```
1)  Amit    Physics  80
2)  Rahul   Maths    90
3)  Shyam   Biology  87
4)  Kedar   English  85
5)  Hari    History  89
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last?answertab=votes#tab-top

The following code also work as expected.

```
awk '{print $0}' marks.txt  | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3 "\t"$4}'
```

I don't understand  `awk '{$1=""; print $0}' marks.txt` Even though now intuitively make sense.

Comment: Are you asking for explanation what does `awk '{$1=""; print $0}' marks.txt` do? It's explained in SO question you linked: _Print all but the first column:_

Comment: $1="" seems make sense. But I guess I am ask $1="" manual reference.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that that is not a good approach to print all columns from the Nth to the last since it also changes the white space between the columns and needs an additional step to remove the leading white space it leaves behind since it's not deleting the field, it's just changing it to null and leaving the separator(s) around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$1=""; print $0` clears the first field and recalculates the whole line before printing it. This is documented in the [Changing Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) section of the GAWK manual:

> When the value of a field is changed (as perceived by `awk`), the text of the input record is recalculated to contain the new field where the old one was. In other words, `$0` changes to reflect the altered field.

This is true in all implementations of AWK, it’s not a GNU extension; *The AWK Programming Language* describes this behaviour as follows:

> This is important: when `$0` is changed by assignment or substitution, `$1`, `$2`, etc., and `NF` will be recomputed; likewise, when one of `$1`, `$2`, etc., is changed, `$0` is reconstructed using `OFS` to separate fields.

Comment: I would like to add that this way the separator before the second column is preserved.

Comment: Wish they'd said "reconstructed" instead of "recalculated" in the docs. "Recalculated" makes it sound like what's happening is just a math operation whereas $0 is actually being rebuilt from it's fields plus the OFS string.

Comment: To confuse (or maybe help clarify) matters further, see also `echo a b c | awk '{$1=""; $0 = $0; $1 = $1; print $0}'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, thanks! I was wondering why the first field simply did not disappear. So it's not as simple as just setting `$1` to an empty string, you also have to provoke `awk` to re-form `$0`.

Comment: Note that FS is involved in regenerating $1, $2, NF... when $0 is modified, while it's OFS that is involved to regenerate $0 when $1, $2... (and NF with some implementations) are modified.